# UserControl with Label and ContentStringFormat as Binding

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a Usercontrol which contains a Label. The I'm binding the Content-Property to a double and the ContentStringFormat-Property to a String. I use it to display percent Values, but the formatting must be configurable.

Here is the XAML for the specific part:

```
<Label Name="lbl_percent"
       Content="{Binding ValuePercentage, ElementName=userControl}"
       ContentStringFormat="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=FontFormat}"
       Foreground="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=TextColor}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
```

It works as expected, but with one specific problem. The comma is not what I expect.

If I have a system with 'de-de' I expect it to be:

```
    expected     shown
    25,3         25.3
```

How can I fix this? I alredy tried to add a covnerterCulture with CurrentCulture, but this shows an error (its still working with point instead of comma):

> Das Element "CurrentCulture" wurde nicht erkannt, oder es kann nicht auf das Element zugegriffen werden.

Which translates too:

> The Element "CurrentCulture" was not recognized, or the item could not be accessed.

How can I fix this? The StringFormat must be bindable.

Comment: You could set `Language="de-DE"` or just `Language="de"` on the Label.

Comment: de-de was just an exmaple, it can and will be used also on other environments where it can be NOT de-de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FrameworkElement class has a Language property that you can bind to an XmlLanguage source property:

```
<Label Name="lbl_percent"
   Content="{Binding ValuePercentage, ElementName=userControl}"
   ContentStringFormat="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=FontFormat}"
   Foreground="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=TextColor}"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
   Language="{Binding TheLang, ElementName=userControl}" />
```

---

```
private readonly System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage _lang = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("de-DE");
public System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage TheLang => _lang;
```

But if you want this to be dynamic you might as well add another property to your source object that returns a string that is already formatted according to your "FontFormat" and a specific culture, e.g.:

```
    public string FormattedValuePercentage
    {
        get
        {
            return ValuePercentage.ToString(FontFormat, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"));
        }
    }
```

...and bind the Label's Content property to this one directly:

```
<Label Name="lbl_percent"
   Content="{Binding FormattedValuePercentage, ElementName=userControl}" />
```

Comment: Actually, the `Language` property is bindable, although not to a string. Its type is `XmlLanguage`.

Comment: This helped, thanks. I just had to add a setter fpr this and update it when the double Value changed to get the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You may bind the `Language` property of the Label to a property of type `XmlLanguage` in your view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public XmlLanguage Language { get; set; } = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("de");
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<Label ... Language="{Binding Language}" />
```

Comment: I will try that later, for now, @mm8 's solution helped me.